# SharePoint 2010 Organizational Browser

Tags: organization-browser, my-profile

I'm trying to find a way to modify the SharePoint 2010 Organizational Browser (Silverlight control) by adding additional user properties.  I've done some digging and I think the actual web part is called the ProfileBrowser.  I also think this webpart is within the Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls namespace.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to find the original source for this ProfileBrowser web part in order to modify it with additional properties?

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is to see if you can create a class which extends from the ProfileBrowser and add your own properties.

Otherwise (ie: if it's sealed) then you'll have to start from scratch. The source generally isn't available for propriety Microsoft Products.